# Converting boolean values into integer value in SQL

Tags: sql, binary, integer, boolean

I'm trying to create a function in SQL but I don't know how to start, this is the case...

Let's say I have 4 boolean variables which are A, B, C and D. So if I have the variable B and D as true or 1, I want to save that combination in a single integer field. for that I need to assign diferent values to each variable like A=1 B=2 C=4 D=16, so in this order my integer value for the combination B and D should be 18. So all of this calculation it's good.

The function what I need to have it's the reverse process, I'm thinking on have 2 parameters, the Variable (A, B, C or D) and the integer value stored on the table (in this case 18) and the result must be a boolean value, so that way I could know if the variable it's true or not.

This should be the results with each variable...

```
Select fnGetBoolValue('A', 18) /*0 False*/
Select fnGetBoolValue('B', 18) /*1 True*/
Select fnGetBoolValue('C', 18) /*0 False*/
Select fnGetBoolValue('D', 18) /*1 True*/
```

I will appreciate your help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Which RDBMS platform you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of at least 2 ways to do this.

The below works for MySQL and should also work for SQL Server as well.

1: You can brute force all of the combinations (this is the long way)

```
CREATE TABLE CombinationValues
(
CombinationString CHAR(2),
CombinationValue INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO CombinationValues VALUES
('AA',2),
('AB',3),
('AC',6),
('AD',17),
('BA',3),
('BB',4),
('BC',6),
('BD',18),
('CA',5),
('CB',6),
('CC',8),
('CD',20),
('DA',17),
('DB',18),
('DC',20),
('DD',16);

SELECT COUNT(1) > 0 AS `Result`
FROM CombinationValues
WHERE CombinationString LIKE '%D%'
AND CombinationValue = 18;
```

2: Then the shorter way, that's easier to extend:

```
CREATE TABLE CombinationValues
(
CombinationString CHAR(2),
CombinationValue INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO CombinationValues VALUES
('A',1),
('B',2),
('C',4),
('D',16);

SELECT COUNT(1) > 0 AS `Result`
FROM CombinationValues p
INNER JOIN CombinationValues c ON p.CombinationString != c.CombinationString AND p.CombinationString = 'B'
WHERE p.CombinationValue + c.CombinationValue = 18;
```

You just need to add parameters and then turn it into a function.